# Move Cursor to another cell in DataGridView - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I Have a `DataGridView` with 6 `column`.

```
Column1 = "Product ID"   //ReadOnly False
COlumn2 = "Product Name" //ReadOnly True - Auto Fill After Product ID Entered
COlumn3 = "Product Info" //ReadOnly True - Auto Fill After Product ID Entered
Column4 = "Price"        //ReadOnly False
Column5 = "Qty"          //ReadOnly False
Column6 = "Sub Total"    //ReadOnly True - Auto Fill From Price*Qty
```

How can I only use tab on Cell where the `ReadOnly` set to `False` ? I mean, if I aleady input product `ID` and press "Enter", the cursor / focus move to `Column4` and so move to `Column5` after I hit "Enter" again in `Column4` and add new row after press "Enter" again in `Column5`.

Allready tried others code but only works for all cell not specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?735207-DAtaGridView-move-to-next-column-automatically

Did you try this site? Sorry i cannot post to your comment section because it requires 50 reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, really aprreciate it. Would check this later at home.

Answer (score 0):

I use this so far to make it move to another cell using Enter Keys. Using code from Arsalan Tamiz [Blog](http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.com/2008/07/making-enter-key-move-to-next.html).

```
Dim celWasEndEdit As DataGridViewCell
Private _EnterMoveNext As Boolean = True
```

```
<System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(True)>
    Public Property OnEnterKeyMoveNext() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _EnterMoveNext
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _EnterMoveNext = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

```
Private Sub DataGridView_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
        'if Enter Move Next should work andalso mouse button was NOT down
        'we are checking mouse buttons because if select was changed
        'by Mouse then we will NOT do our Enter Move Next
        If _EnterMoveNext AndAlso MouseButtons = 0 Then
            'if selection is changed after Cell Editing
            If celWasEndEdit IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell IsNot Nothing Then
                'if we are currently in the next line of last edit cell
                If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex = celWasEndEdit.RowIndex + 1 AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex Then
                    Dim iColNew As Integer
                    Dim iRowNew As Integer

                    'if we at the last column
                    If celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >= DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 2 Then
                        iColNew = 0                         'move to first column
                        iRowNew = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex   'and move to next row
                    Else 'else it means we are NOT at the last column move to next column
                        iColNew = celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex + 1
                        'but row should remain same
                        iRowNew = celWasEndEdit.RowIndex
                    End If
                    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(iColNew, iRowNew)   ' ok set the current column
                End If
            End If
            celWasEndEdit = Nothing                      ' reset the cell end edit
        End If
    End Sub
```

And for the bypass. I use this (But i don't think its the perfect one, because if i press Left Arrow on Column 4 to move to Column 0, the focus can't move to it, maybe because i put Keys.Sender Right)

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEnter
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).ReadOnly = True Then
            SendKeys.Send("{Right}")
        End If
    End Sub
```